# jQuery error TypeError: $.event.handle is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, runtime-error, jquery-masonry

I am using latest jQuery for jQuery.masonry its throwing following error: on line 47 in jquery-1.9.1.min.js

```
TypeError: $.event.handle is undefined
```

if any one is having same error ?

MyCode:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#content');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.post',
        isAnimated: true
      });
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.wp-pagenavi',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '.wp-pagenavi a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.post',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
        }
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          // show elems now they're ready
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );

  });
</script>
```

Comment: [It seems that masonry does not work with jQuery 1.9 because $.event.handle returns undefined](https://github.com/desandro/masonry/pull/281). A link to a github with all the info you need.

Comment: Yes I think you are right as I have seen that with old liberary its not the issues, but another one that is too much recursive error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The function has been deprecated: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#other-undocumented-properties-and-methods

You can use $.event.dispatch instead.

In addition or alternatively to using the dispatch function you can add the Migrate plugin, http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/, which will add back in $.event.handle so you able to fix the code without breaking the application.

Comment: Awesome, after recent WordPress update to 5.5 the auto-scroll js stopped working, the error was: `i.event.handle` but now is after changing to `i.event.dispatch` issue resolved. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use :

```
var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
```

as an element :

```
$newElems.imagesLoaded
```

Maybe this is the problem.

A solution would be :

```
 var $newElems = $( newElements );
 $newElems.css({ opacity: 0 });
```

Comment: How different is your code from the OP's other than removing the chaining

Comment: I don't know if you think that the variable doesn't return the jQuery object, but it surely does. I think you've been mislead somewhere.

Comment: I have just checked this, you are all right, but it seems to turn the code really confusing

Comment: Thanks @EricMartins but the issue is in dispatch event

Comment: I am really sorry @justnajm , it will not happen again