# Infinite scroll with masonry

Tags: jquery

i would like to aplogoize before my question, because this topic is many times in stackoverflow, but i'm not as good at jquery and javascript to solve this...

I would like to have infinite scrolling with masonry, so i download the demo source code to my computer and i want to play with its settings, and so on for using in my projects. But, i've stucked at the beginning.

I would like to reach this situation: http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/infinite-scroll.html

I've downloaded all source code from this site and paste it into mine, but it's not working.

Demo: http://marygate.cz/aaaa/

I'm sorry again for my bad knowledge, but for me this is really hard...

Thanks very much for anwers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look to be using a newer version of jquery.

When loading your page i get the error

[13:35:44.251] TypeError: $.event.handle is undefined @ http://marygate.cz/aaaa/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js:47

then doing a quick search on this error I found this
[jQuery error TypeError: $.event.handle is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527658/jquery-error-typeerror-event-handle-is-undefined)

$.event.handle was deprecated in V1.9 your using v2.0.3 and the example you was looking is using v1.7.1

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. I hope i'll figure how to have this with mysql loading products out. Thanks again :)

Comment: No.. implementation in my site isnt working... But i'm doing exactly the same! Could you help me, please? :( demo: www.marygate.cz/beta