# Not sure why i am getting an error cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: jquery

Not sure why i am getting an error cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. I am trying to have a bar show up when page is not scrolling and when page is scrolling to animate the opacity back down to 0. However when i load the page i get the error above. Not sure how to fix this problem or why i am getting this error. any help would be great, thank you.

Here is ERROR i receive:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Here is my Script

```
var special = jQuery.event.special,
    uid1 = 'D' + (+new Date()),
    uid2 = 'D' + (+new Date() + 1);

special.scrollstart = {
    setup: function() {

        var timer,
            handler =  function(evt) {

                var _self = this,
                    _args = arguments;

                if (timer) {
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                } else {
                    evt.type = 'scrollstart';
                    jQuery.event.handle.apply(_self, _args);
                }

                timer = setTimeout( function(){
                    timer = null;
                }, special.scrollstop.latency);

            };

        jQuery(this).bind('scroll', handler).data(uid1, handler);

    },
    teardown: function(){
        jQuery(this).unbind( 'scroll', jQuery(this).data(uid1) );
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean `jQuery.Event.handle.apply`? (capital E)

Comment: I just tried switching with a capital E and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: For me it was conflict with 2 jQuery libs loaded at once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.event.handle
```

Is [deprecated](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#other-undocumented-properties-and-methods) since it was removed in version 1.9 of jQuery.

Therefor you can not use properties of it since it's not defined.

You can use the following instead:

```
$.event.dispatch
```

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16527658/jquery-error-typeerror-event-handle-is-undefined).

Comment: So i don't get the error anymore but the script doesn't seem to be working at all. which sucks cause now i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I ended up putting it in wrong. your fix was perfect, thank you so much.